# angular javascript cleaning URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a SPA application developed using AngularJS. Access to the application can take place in two ways:

1) By entering the address (example) `www.example.com`, or

2) By clicking on a link like `http://www.example.com?do=this&param=1234`

When the application is started, it examines the URL and, if suitable parameters are found, it prompts the user to log-in/register and then goes to a specific page within the application where the visitor is supposed to perform some activities related to the action `this` with parameter `1234`.

Traversal through pages is handled by the javascript command:

`$window.location.href="#/other_page;`.

This works ok so far, except that the URL is kept with the parameters. As such, whenever the application decides that it needs to go to another page, the URL (in the address bar of the browser) would look like:

`http://www.example.com?do=this&param=1234#/other_page`

which is messing the behavior of the application.

My question is: Once I was able to extract from the original URL the received parameters, I want to **clean** the url and proceed with its normal contents, which would be something like:

`http://www.example.com#/other_page`.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using $location service clear the search query params from address bar of the browser.

Syntax is:

```
$location.search({});
```

For Example After finished your login or register page.

```
$scope.login = function(){
   // Check your logic and clear search params
    if($routeParams && $routeParams.src)
   {
       $location.search({});
       $location.path($scope.baseurl+$routeParams.src);
   }
};
```

Here am using $routeParams service you could also check $window.location.search

Comment: Hello @PrakashA, your solution does not work either (much the same result as the one suggested by Vivek above).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service. It says:

> Changes to the URL in the address bar are reflected into $location service and changes to $location are reflected into the browser address bar.

So, basically you can do:

`$location.path('other_page')`

which should clear the URL and set this path instead.

Comment: Hello @vivek. I just tested your solution and, unfortunately, it does not work as described.

Comment: Hello @vivek. I found a working solution. See my own answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a working solution. I use the following command:

```
$window.location.href = location.protocol          + 
                        "//"                       + 
                        location.host              + 
                        "/index.html#/other_page"    ;
```

which makes the trick. Perhaps not the most elegant, but it works as needed.

Thank you guys (@vivek and @prakashA) for your support.

Comment: Well.... It works, but it doesn't. I'll open a new question with more details of the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749052/angularjs-spa-application-cleaning-url).