# AngularJS SPA application, "cleaning" URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a second and more detailed question of my previous post ([angular javascript cleaning URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35716142/angular-javascript-cleaning-url/35716343?noredirect=1#comment59158559_35716343)) which I thought I found a solution, but didn't.

I have an SPA application built with AngularJS. Normally, the user would log into the site and perform various activities, each managed by a specific subpage (and controller).

When the user logs into the application, information is extracted from a remote database and added to the `$rootScope` object. This information can be used by the various pages (and hence it is made available globally).

Users may also receive a link to the application with parameters, for instance: `http://www.example.com?action=fillform&formid=234lkhjwefj234lofjwodjfw3e`.

When the link is clicked, the application checks if there are parameters in the URL and, if yes, pops a modal showing some information related to the form to be filled and offers to log into the system (if the visitor already has an account) or register. Let's assume that the user has an account.

When the user selects to log into the application, the modal handles the login process and then needs to **move** the application to the applicable sub-page. Here is where the problem begins...

I initially used the javascript command:

```
$window.location.href = "#fill_form?ID=234lkhjwefj234lofjwodjfw3e
```

which brings me correctly to the page and specific form, but makes the URL shown in the address bar of the browser to be: `http://www.example.com?action=fillform&formid=234lkhjwefj234lofjwodjfw3e#/fill_form?ID=234lkhjwefj234lofjwodjfw3e`.

Moreover, any additional redirection would still contain the first part of the URL (i.e. `http://www.example.com?action=fillform&formid=234lkhjwefj234lofjwodjfw3e`).

Besides the ugliness, it causes issues when the user clicks other links in the page (that would normally bring the user to a different sub-page).

Then, I tried using the command:

```
$window.location.href = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/index.html#/fill_form?ID=" + l_ID ;
```

(where `l_ID` contains `234lkhjwefj234lofjwodjfw3e`).

This removed the part of the parameters received with the link but, apparently, it fully refreshes the application context because the information retrieved from the database related to the user is no longer available.

So, I need a way to be able to traverse through sub-pages while removing the parameters of the initial link and retaining the information retrieved in the initial step/session.

Comment: Is server involved in reading the `action` and `fill-form` or is it only used within angular? If no server involvement and only angular you can use the angular search part and store it in a service. Once stored you can clear the search with `$location` service

Comment: Thanks @charliettl for your response. No. The analysis of the initial URL is fully done within the javascript. As per your suggestion, I'm not sure I understand it. Could you provide a simple example (sniper perhaps) of what you mean?

Comment: `example.com/#/?param1=1&param2=2` ... when you use `$location.search()` can retrieve object, store that object, then reset `$location.search()` per docs. Then you have clean URL and stored data. Could also put it into localStorage if needed

Comment: Hummmm. still unclear. I was hoping you could provide a COPY-PASTE example. Will try to dig into the documentation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How are you currently reading those values?

Comment: The initial controller (let's call it "indexController") checks if there are parameters. If yes, it retrieves some information from the DB, adds it to the `$rootScope`, and opens the modal. The modal has its own controller that looks at `$rootScope` and does its job. In fact, immediately after the `indexController` extracts the params of the URL, I don't need them anymore and hence can be removed.

Comment: Right...so if they are set within angular `search` context you can easily clear them with `$location` service

Comment: Make yourself a very simple route in your app with a simple controller and a couple of buttons that let you change the angular search in url using `$location`

Comment: OK, will give it a try. Thanks.